# Python Multiprocessing does not work parallel

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

When I run the code it is working in order not in parallel. What am I doing wrong(totally newbie in multiprocessing)

Output of code:
*['p1 0', 'p1 1', 'p1 2', 'p1 3', 'p1 4', 'p1 5', 'p1 6', 'p1 7', 'p1 8', 'p1 9', 'p2 0', 'p2 1', 'p2 2', 'p2 3', 'p2 4', 'p2 5', 'p2 6', 'p2 7', 'p2 8', 'p2 9']*

```
def worker1(listvariable):
    for i in range(10):
        listvariable.append("p1 "+str(i))

def worker2(listvariable):
    for i in range(10):
        listvariable.append("p2 "+str(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import multiprocessing



    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()

    sharedlist = manager.list()



    



    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(
target=worker1, args=[sharedlist]
)
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(
target=worker2, args=[sharedlist]
)

    process1.start()
    process2.start()
    process1.join()
    process2.join()

    print(sharedlist)
```

Comment: Your workload is too simple `worker1` will complete before `worker2` is spawned.

Comment: Is there a way to get output as  **['p1 0', 'p2 0', 'p1 1', 'p2 1']** Thanks for the answer btw @KlausD.

Comment: This sound like an x y problem. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this?

Comment: Well like you said my workload is to shallow for the parallel running but I want to run them parallel anyways that is the main problem I mean I want to get this output  ['p1 0', 'p2 0', 'p1 1', 'p2 1']  even workload not enough

Comment: You did not answer my last question.

Comment: Well worker1 gettin data with request from an api and adding that data to list1 at the same time worker2 getting that data and using it for calculation so it has to be parallel because there is worker3 and worker4 using list1 for calculation as well If I wait for the all worker in order to complete their calculations, I lost data from api because I need to get data every 100ms so I cant wait to all functions to end their progress that is why I am using multiprocessing

Comment: Well, while processes can run in parallel, they don't run in order or in sync. If you need to synchronize the flow of data, let the process drop the data into queues and have the main process collect and order them as needed.

Comment: You cannot get whitespace like this  p1 0.